# Prawn PDF: render a set of things on the same page

Tags: ruby, prawn

I am looking for a way to do the following

```
pdf.on_same_page do
   pdf.text "foo"
   pdf.imaage bar
   pdf.table(baz)
   ....
end
```

In other words, I am wanting to group several elements such that if the entire group can fit on the page, render it on the same page, otherwise page break and render it all on the next page (assuming the entire group can fit on a single page)
how would such a thing be accomplished?

Comment: I understand what you want, but I can't think exactly of a way to do it. There's an option to simulate a render of a TextBox, called dry_run. You can look into that to calculate the text's height. With the image, you can either get the height information before, or set a fixed height, so you'll know the exact height. Finally, with the table, you can also calculate how many rows it has and set the height of each row. This way you can manually calculate the size of it all.

Comment: I don't think Prawn has a method to automatically calculate the height of things, or to move things to a new page if it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a slightly different approach, but using tables.

```
footer_table = pdf.make_table(data) do
  cells.borders = []
  row(0).font_style = :bold
  row(2).font_style = :bold
end
pdf.start_new_page if (pdf.cursor - footer_table.height).negative?
footer_table.draw
```

Given `pdf` is the pdf document, I only put the table if it fits the page.